# How to integrate the Fusioncharts library with Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, theming, charts

I have been trying to integrate the [Fusioncharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/) library with my Drupal 7 site.

Just to check if everything is working properly, I followed [this documentation](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/guide-for-web-developers/php/PHP_BasicExample.html) for creating a basic graph with data contained in Data.xml file; the entire documentation is [here](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/).

FYI, I need to use PHP as I am more comfortable with it.

I have extracted the downloaded folder into /sites/all/libraries/FusionChartsFree/; with changes in paths (nothing else); I have pasted the code in the given example into my Drupal 7 node with the php input filter enabled. I also have the [libraries](http://drupal.org/project/libraries) module installed.

```
<?php
  //We've included ../Includes/FusionCharts_Gen.php, which contains FusionCharts PHP Class
  //to help us easily embed the charts.
  $name = "FusionChartsFree";
  if ($path = libraries_get_path($name)) {
    include $path . '/Code/PHP/Includes/FusionCharts.php';
  }
?>
<html>
  <head>      
    <?php
      //You need to include the following JS file, if you intend to embed the chart using JavaScript.
      //When you make your own charts, make sure that the path to this JS file is correct. Else, you
      //would get JavaScript errors.

      include($path.'/Code/FusionCharts/FusionCharts.js');
    ?> 
    <script type="Javascript" SRC="/sites/all/libraries/FusionChartsFree/Code/FusionCharts/FusionCharts.js"></SCRIPT>
    <title>FusionCharts - Simple Column 3D Chart</title> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      //Create the chart - Column 3D Chart with data from Data/Data.xml
      echo renderChart("/sites/all/libraries/FusionChartsFree/Code/FusionCharts/Column3D.swf", "/sites/all/libraries/FusionChartsFree/Code/PHP/BasicExample/Data/Data.xml", "", "myFirst", 600, 300, false, true); 
   ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

I get the below output. It is pretty long; hence, I have put then in part by part in these pictures.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

(FYI, those Flash files that appear in the output, do not display anything if I click on them.)

Now, suppose I remove the below line from the code.

```
<?php
 include $path . '/Code/FusionCharts/FusionCharts.js';
?>
```

I get nothing. I mean only a text which reads "cahrt" in the below output.

[image]

**My Question**: How can I make Fusioncharts work in DRUPAL 7?

I am also having similar trouble with the [pChart](http://www.pchart.net/) library too: Even pChart does not display anything, not even an error, or warning. Simply there is nothing in the node body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it worked. I don't know exactly what the problem is, but here is what I did.

- I uninstalled all other modules related to charting
- I downloaded FusionchartFree again
- I sed the [Libraries](http://drupal.org/project/libraries) module
- I checked with the following code, and it worked.

  ```
  $name = "FusionChartsFree";
  if ($path = libraries_get_path($name)) {    
    include $path . '/Code/PHP/Includes/FusionCharts.php';
    drupal_add_js($path.'/Code/FusionCharts/FusionCharts.js');
  }

  // Create the chart - Column 3D Chart with data from Data/Data.xml

  echo renderChart($path.'/Charts/FCF_Column3D.swf', $path.'/Code/PHP/BasicExample/Data/Data.xml', "", "myFirst", 600, 300, false, true);
  ```

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of problems in your code:

- `include($path.'/Code/PHP/Includes/FusionCharts.php');` you have to use `./` to include files.
- `include($path.'/Code/FusionCharts/FusionCharts.js');` you should use [`drupal_add_js()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) to include javascript in your code.
- FusionCharts documentation seems a little old as `Column3D.swf` is now `FCF_Column3D.swf`

Here is a working example, I haven't used the librarie module but you should be able to adapt it easily. I put this code in a node with PHP filter activated.

```
<?php
$file = './sites/all/libraries/FusionChartsFree/Code/PHP/Includes/FusionCharts.php';
if (is_file($file)) {
  require_once $file;
}
drupal_add_js('sites/all/libraries/FusionChartsFree/Code/FusionCharts/FusionCharts.js');

//Create the chart - Column 3D Chart with data from Data/Data.xml
echo renderChart("/sites/all/libraries/FusionChartsFree/Code/FusionCharts/FCF_Column3D.swf", "/sites/all/libraries/FusionChartsFree/Code/PHP/BasicExample/Data/Data.xml", "", "myFirst", 600, 300, false, true); 

?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much..!! But still I have small problem,  I get a flash player icon hwere I can click it load the graph. but when I click it, its empty..!

Comment: before I click,  http://oi44.tinypic.com/300s0i8.jpg    after I click, http://oi39.tinypic.com/33z7f5v.jpg

Comment: Also can you tell me how to do it in phpclass.of fusionchart..? I followed this documentation , made the necessary cahnges as u said (about the path and adding js) http://docs.fusioncharts.com/free/Contents/PHPClass_BasicExamples.html . But all I see is a text "chart" on my node.FYI, I tried both examples given on that page and got same results. Am getting too frustrated with this..:( So please help me.

Comment: This is rather strange, using the code as is works for me in chrome: http://i.imgur.com/UzWFx.png
For the PHPClass the only important thing is to get the `  $FC->setSwfPath("../../FusionCharts/");` path correctly.

Comment: I done everything properly..!! I have no idea what to do.. how can I create graphs now..?? I tried flot module but even that having problems,http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23588/using-flot-with-drupal-7

Comment: Do u know any other way I can create graphs in D7..?? What's the solution to my problem now..??

Comment: Double check your paths to see if everything is in the right place. Try on a clean new Drupal 7 install.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the paths, I checked..! Am gonna give another try on a new d7 install...

Comment: could there be some other module which is interfering with the working of fusioncharts..? or could there be some otherthings need to be installed for it to work..?? for eg., do I need swftools..? (its required for openflashchart, and fusioonchart is also a flash chart. but there is no d7 version of swftools yet.) Can you tell me what are th external modules you have installed, so that I can cross check and see if anything is wrong with one that I have installed..??

Comment: Hey, I tried with all other modules except core modules uninstalled and it still didn't work..!!